# How to use regex assertions in SOAP UI

Tags: soapui

I was playing around with some old SOAP UI script, and noticed some very basic failure like this

Somehow one extra new space/line was getting added in the expected assertions like 
ApplicationError

Actual did not have any new line. That's why it failed.

I am new to this tool, I was googling through, and found out, I can use REG ex, and enabled use token as RegEX and added like

ApplicationError\b+

I assumed, \b would catch one white space, but i am not seeing difference, its still failing. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you could provide a [mcve], maybe we could help you.

Answer (score 0):

SoapUI is a Java program, and the scripts used are Groovy, which is derived from Java.

Thus I would expect it to follow this:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

...and I would expect you to catch the whitespace with \s and not \b

If you want to use the \b, I would suspect the + modifier is incorrect. I would expect you should use the ? or nothing at all.